# react-native-image-picker getting reverse height and width

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-image-picker

I am using react-native-image-picker library to capture image code as follow:

```
launchImageLibrary({
   includeExtra: false,
   mediaType: "photo",
   selectionLimit: 0,
   quality: 1,
   maxWidth: 1000,
   maxHeight: 1500
}, (res)=>{
   console.log(res);
});
```

When I am taking capture using android real device(portrait) getting image with following:

```
{
   uri: "string",
   height: 1000,
   width: 750
}
```

Expected and correct response:

```
{
   uri: "string",
   height: 750,
   width: 1000
}
```

can someone help me out?

Comment: it is following aspect ratio. so, you should use another library to resizing. Ex: react-native-image-resizer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I advice you to use react-native-image-crop-picker library.

The code below works for me. You can use it without cropping if you do not need it.

```
import ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-crop-picker';

ImagePicker.openCamera({
  width: 768,
  height: 1024,
  cropping: false,
}).then(image => {
  console.log(image)
})
```

Looks like we have same aspect ratio 3/4. So I guess it may help you.

Comment: It's looks good library. I will try and see in both platforms.

Answer (score 1):

On android, i have the same problem on cropping the photo. The width are inverted by the height on the new photo cropped.

I fix the problem by removing the original width and height.
(But for Ios, the original width and height are important)

```
import ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-crop-picker'   try {
    ImagePicker.openCropper({
      path: uri,
      // width:2048,
      // height: 4096,
      includeExif: true,
      hideBottomControls: true,
      waitAnimationEnd: false,
      cropperChooseText: 'ok',
      cropperCancelText: 'Cancel',
    }).then(async image => {
      callback(image.path)
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

I was still getting this issue using the latest 'react-native-image-crop-picker' library.

I have a simple fix that I am using.

After calling the Image Picker like this:

```
let result = await ImagePicker.openPicker({...myparams, includeExif: true});
```

I check if the exif orientation is greater than four and if so I swap the height and width returned from Image Picker.

```
if (result.path) {
  const exif = (
    (imagePickerResult.exif && "Orientation" in imagePickerResult.exif)?
      Number(imagePickerResult.exif["Orientation"]): 0
  );

  rotate = (exif > 4)? true: false;

  // ignore the function here just showing how I swap the height & width
  return await getResizedDisplayImage(
    result.path,
    rotate? result.height: result.width,
    rotate? result.width: result.height,
    maxSize
  )
}
```

see: https://sirv.com/help/articles/rotate-photos-to-be-upright/